# How to get polygons of a shapefile containing centroids of polygons from another shapefile in R?

Tags: r, gis

I'm working with two shapefiles in R and I'm trying to select the polygons of one of them which contains the centroids of another shp.

I've been able to get the centroids of each file separately (attached image), but I can't find a way to accomplish the task described above. In the example, let's say I want to get only polygons (shp1) with blue centroids (from shp2) inside of them.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0HzU.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `gCentroid()` and `gContains()` from the **rgeos** package:

```
library(raster) ## For data and functions used to make example SpatialPolygons objects
library(rgeos)  ## For topological operations on geometries

## Make a couple of example SpatialPolygons objects, p1 & p2
p1 <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
r <- raster(extent(p1))
r[] <- 1:10
p2 <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve=TRUE)

## Find centroids of p2
cc <- gCentroid(p2, byid=TRUE)

## Select Polygons in p1 that contain at least one of centroids from p2
p3 <- p1[apply(gContains(p1, cc, byid=TRUE), 2, any),]

## Plot to check that that worked
ared <- adjustcolor("red", alpha=0.6)
plot(p1)
plot(p3, add=TRUE, col="wheat")
plot(p2, add=TRUE, border=ared)
points(cc, pch=16, col=ared)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked in a nice and elegant way. But now I have another question... 
If I wanted to get the polygons of each shapefile containing the centroids of the other shapefile, how could I do this? Something like, at the same time, obtaining that "the centroid of x is in y" and "the centroid of y is in x". Don't know if my explanation is good enough...
Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mean something like `ii <- apply(gContains(p1, cc, byid=TRUE), 2, any); xx <- gCentroid(p1, byid=TRUE)[ii]; points(xx, col="blue")` ?

Comment: Ops! Sorry I didn't answer before. It worked good in a visual way. Thanks for the answer again!